# I can not run my JUnit tests anymore

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I have a project with two modules and starting this morning whenever i try to run my JUnit tests on both modules i get this error in my gradle build

> Error:Execution failed for task ':usecases:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

usecases is one of my modules.

[image]

```
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':usecases:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:45)
    at net.ltgt.gradle.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.execute(ErrorProneCompiler.java:75)
    at net.ltgt.gradle.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.execute(ErrorProneCompiler.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:206)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:130)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at net.ltgt.gradle.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.execute(ErrorProneCompiler.java:63)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:93)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:87)
    at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneJavaCompiler$1.call(BaseErrorProneJavaCompiler.java:99)
    at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneCompiler.run(BaseErrorProneCompiler.java:137)
    at com.google.errorprone.BaseErrorProneCompiler.run(BaseErrorProneCompiler.java:108)
    at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.run(ErrorProneCompiler.java:119)
    at com.google.errorprone.ErrorProneCompiler.compile(ErrorProneCompiler.java:66)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.realm.processor.ModuleMetaData.getClassMetaDataFromModule(ModuleMetaData.java:130)
    at io.realm.processor.ModuleMetaData.generate(ModuleMetaData.java:85)
    at io.realm.processor.RealmProcessor.processModules(RealmProcessor.java:218)
    at io.realm.processor.RealmProcessor.process(RealmProcessor.java:160)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:826)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:742)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$2000(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:100)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1046)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1153)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1120)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:814)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl$1.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl$1.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:93)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:128)
    ... 44 more
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

apply plugin: "net.ltgt.errorprone"

version = "1.0.1"
group = "com.github.zeyad-37"

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'usecases'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.github.zeyad-37'
    libraryName = 'UseCases'
    artifact = 'usecases'

    libraryDescription = 'Is a library that is a generic implementation of the Domain and Data layers in a clean architecture.'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/Zeyad-37/UseCases'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/Zeyad-37/UseCases.git'

    libraryVersion = version

    developerId = 'zeyad-37'
    developerName = 'Zeyad Gasser'
    developerEmail = 'zeyad.gasser@gmail.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-errorprone-plugin:0.0.10"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        //lint rules of conduct
        warningsAsErrors true
        abortOnError true
        htmlReport true
        //locations for the rules and output
        lintConfig file("${rootDir}/config/lint/lint-config.xml")
        htmlOutput file("${buildDir}/reports/lint/lint.html")
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.all {
            // All the usual Gradle options.
            jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=256m'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        incremental false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.3.1'
    retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
    okhttpVersion = '3.8.0'
    androidSupportTest = '0.5'
    espressoCore = '2.2.2'
    powerMock = '1.6.6'
    robolectric = '3.3.2'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //Job Dispatcher
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.6.0'
    // Network
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttpVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttpVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
    // Rx
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
    // Cache
    compile('com.github.lowlevel-studios:storo:1.1.0') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // Testing
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
    testCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoCore"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:$robolectric"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:$robolectric"

    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:$powerMock"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:$powerMock"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:$powerMock"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:$powerMock"
}

apply from: "$project.rootDir/tools/script-git-version.gradle"
apply from: "$project.rootDir/tools/script-findbugs.gradle"
apply from: "$project.rootDir/tools/script-pmd.gradle"
apply from: "$project.rootDir/tools/script-java-code-coverage.gradle"
apply from: "$project.rootDir/tools/script-infer.gradle"
apply from: "$project.rootDir/tools/script-check-style.gradle"
```

Comment: A single stack trace line isn't much helpful. Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: There is not any more more stack trace, i uploaded a screen shot

Comment: @ZeyadGasser there is, it even tells you where. Look at the `Gradle Console` tool window.

Comment: @Vampire I added the gradle stack trace. It was not very helpful for me and I thought that it was too big to put

Comment: Are you able to do a normal build and generate an apk? Can you post your `build.gradle` files?

Comment: Also it seems the issue is with realm dependency. See if [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2563) helps.

Comment: It is helpful. Now you can go to https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/v3.3.1/realm/realm-annotations-processor/src/main/java/io/realm/processor/ModuleMetaData.java for your version and look for the error. If you don't see it, get the code, open it in your IDE, set a breakpoint at line 130, run Gradle with `-Dorg.grade.debug=true, attach the debugger to port 5005 and then investigate why there is the NPE. After you found it, make it work for your project and also report back to realm. It might actually be the same error Abhishek posted when lines shifted a but since it was reported.

Comment: @Vampire I cant seem to get ur suggestion to work.

Comment: @AbhishekJain i added my build.gradle

Comment: Well, a bit more detail would be helpful to help you get it working.

Comment: The `build.gradle` will probably not help much as the problem is either in your `@RealmModule` annotation or in the annotation processor of the realm software you are using.

Comment: I am using realm 3.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added: `apply plugin: 'android-apt'` to my `build.gradle` file. I accidentally removed it earlier.